# Issue converting C# marshal interface code to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm attempting to convert a project from C# to VB.NET to enable drag and dropping of Outlook messages into our program.

The original source can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C?fid=1524694) on CodeProject.

I'm 95% of the way there but having trouble implementing the IStorage interface , a portion of which is outlined below.

```c#
public interface IStorage
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    IStream CreateStream([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string pwcsName,
                         [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfMode,
                         [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int reserved1,
                         [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int reserved2);                
}
```

I've converted it to the following in VB.NET:

```vb
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)>
Function CreateStream(<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByVal pwcsName As String,
                      <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal grfMode As Integer,
                      <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal reserved1 As Integer,
                      <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal reserved2 As Integer) As IStream
```

However, it results in the following error:

> Attribue 'MarshalAsAttribute' cannot be applied to 'CreateStream' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

I'm a little out of my depth here and would really appreciate any *pointers* you may have in helping me solve this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: `As <MarshalAs(UnmanageType.Interface)> IStream` should do it (not tested, it's been ages since I've done any VB.NET). C# needs a clumsy `return: ` override for such attributes, in VB.NET the attribute stays more naturally with the declaration.

Comment: Maybe this will help (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14364cee-e099-46d3-9697-3b05f2f29719/does-istorage-openstream-work-in-vb?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: Nice pun, by the way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the attribute to the return value in this way:

```
Function CreateStream(<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByVal pwcsName As String,
            <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal grfMode As Integer,
            <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal reserved1 As Integer,
            <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal reserved2 As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> IStream
```